# How to get the entire string until the + sign that changes in length?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app that gets a value from an API that looks like this: "Blahblah + blahblah" or "Blah blah + ..." (basically the value preceding the + sign can be one or several words, but the consistency is it is always followed by a space and + sign). How do I use this value and parse only the text that precedes the + sign so I can use it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try ```String.split()``` in your case: ```var words = Blabblab + blahblah".split(" + ");``` and then ```var firstBlahblah = words[0];```

Comment: Thank you, perfect!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = "Blahblah + blahblah".split('+')[0]
console.log (x)  // prints => Blahblah

x = "abc + def".split('+')[0]
console.log (x)  // prints => abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's `.split()` function to split it like this:

`const splitString = string.split(" +")`

This will return an array of substrings of the first string, the first element of which will be there first part of the string before the " +", which you can access by calling `splitString[0]`.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code below:

```js
var x = "Blahblah + blahblah".split('+');
var result = '';
for(let i of x)
{
  result += i.trim();
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Above peoples already give u answer,if u want to avoid white space just trim splitted String

```
var str = "Blahblah + blahblah+Blahblah + blahblah";
var res = str.split("+");
for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++)
{
console.log(res[i].trim());

}
```